# SwingWorker (Thread) doesn't ever die (still lives after reaching "return null;")?

Tags: java, swingworker

I have implemented a SwingWorker performing some operations in a while loop.

```
    worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>()
    {
        public Void doInBackground()
        {
            while(!this.isCancelled())
            {
                //perform operations
            }
            return null;
        }


    };
    worker.execute();
```

I want to cancel the SwingWorker, thus keeping a reference to "worker" and using it's cancel method.

The cancellation basically works just fine (= "return null;" is reached), but the corresponding thread appears to still live (as shown in my debug-window in eclipse) after cancelling and also takes up resources.

So starting several worker threads and cancelling them keeps them alive after stopping to perform the operations in the while loop and they still accumulate a lot of memory even though they are not used anymore.

I don't want the threads to be alive after they are cancelled, am I missing out on something here?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to work. `SwingWorker` uses thread pool under the hood - it means that you are not directly creating threads by creating `SwingWorker`. The whole point, is to make those threads "reusable" because thread creation is expensive. So you have bunch of "worker threads" that will execute some tasks for you.

Be noticed that if you execute another `SwingWorker` after first one is completed and worker thread (the one you see in the debugger) is idle, the task will be executed by that thread insteed of creating new one.

Dont worry about the resources. Worker thread pool will shutdown worker threads if they will be not used for some time.

Comment: In fact, in my program the threads that are supposed to be idle (since they reached "return null;" and have nothing to do i suppose?) do not take over work of another upcoming swingworker-task. Not even if I take the SwingWorker and reuse it's ".execute()" method. Actually a new thread is created then. And that is what I really want to avoid!

Say I have a program, where a user presses a button and then a swingworker continuously calculates something. After pressing another button, the Swingworker shall stop it's calculation and die, or at least stay idle and take over the task of making...

Comment: calculations the next time the first button is pressed. 
In my program, pressing the first button and the second one and repeat this procedure 5 times, it creates 5 different threads taking up significant memory, instead of just reusing the one swingworker thread 5 times or killing it every time the second button is pressed and creating a new one on pressing the first button (to start calculations).

Comment: @freeprogramer233 Well maybe you are using SwingWorker in wrong way, or you think you are launching new workers after previous ones finishes but that is not true, or it is just the discretion of implementation!
If you are really unsatisfied how SwingWorker works, you can always use strict, deterministict ExecutorService - you will be submitting `Runnbale`s to the thread pool insteed of executing new `SwingWorkers`. Good luck!